# Xcode 10 Text bug

Tags: xcode10

I was wondering if anyone else was having an issue where the text is faded or not there in Xcode version 10? I played around in Preferences to see if changing the text font/color would fix it but no luck. Ex. [Screenshot of the text not being in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR9Qq.png) & [Screenshot of faded text in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSJhs.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fixed. I just had to delete Xcode and all Xcode files from my Mac and reinstall. I used https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ to do it.